# Cannot open assembly '/opt/install4j/resource/signcode.exe': No such file or directory

Tags: mono, install4j

Ia m trying to sign our windows exe from a linux machine and following install4j's documentation, it claims the signcode.exe should be in the resources directory.  I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

This was a mono executable that was shipped up to install4j 5.0. Since install4j 5.1, code signing is implemented directly in install4j. See the General Settings->Code Signing steps.